# Get forgot password link in magento2

Tags: magento2, controllers, customer-account

I am trying to get forgot password link in my controller with below code

```
   class CreatePost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
   {
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $customerForgotUrl;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerForgotUrl  
) {
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->_customerForgotUrl = $customerForgotUrl;             
    parent::__construct($context);
}   
  try{
     $user->save(); 
  }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {             
            $url = $this->_customerForgotUrl->getForgotPasswordUrl();
            $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this emails address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get the password and access your account.', $url);
            $this->_messageManager()->addError($message);
        }
```

Its not working. Please anyone suggest on this.

Comment: Seems to me like you are not using execute method. Can you check the updated answer. I have added die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class CreatePost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        try{
            $user->save();
        }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {

            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
            $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this emails address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get the password and access your account.', $url);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Anything i need to construct to use _url? Directly can i use above code?

Comment: No, in the controller it does not need to add anything in  `__construct` because  `__construct` method already in `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Comment: I used your code , its not working

Comment: @jafar, May I have your controller code?

Comment: Updated my code, please take a look.

Comment: @jafar, still that is not full controller code, I presuming that you are using that controller for frontend. I have updated my answer as per your code and it is working for me

Comment: Its working now.

Comment: Great happy to help you and I learn new things.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT - Based on your code

```
class CreatePost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $customerForgotUrl;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerForgotUrl  
) {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_customerForgotUrl = $customerForgotUrl;             
        parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {    
  try{
     $user->save(); 
  }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {             
           echo $url1 = $this->_customerForgotUrl->getForgotPasswordUrl();

           echo $url2 = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
           die();  
            $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this emails address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get the password and access your account.', $url);
            $this->_messageManager()->addError($message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this also, Its not working

Comment: I used this code getting error like this,
   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method at line 
  $url1 = $this->_customerForgotUrl->getForgotPasswordUrl();

Comment: I believe that will not be needed for you. The link will work using $url2. That I wrote just for you to check. You can comment that out.

Comment: so injecting _customerForgotUrl is not required?

Comment: Yes should not be needed, I have updated my answer, the issue with your code was with execute function